# Creating XML file if not exists throwing error

Tags: c#, xml, file

I'm trying to create an XML file if it does not exist:

```
// check if xml file exists. If not, then create
if (!File.Exists(Globals.baseDir + @"emp.xml"))
{
     File.AppendText(Globals.baseDir + @"emp.xml");
     //Also tried File.Create, File.CreateText
}
```

It does create the file. However, later when the program writes to it, then it throws an exception:

> System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:...\emp.xml' because it is being used by another process.

If I run the program a second time, it uses the same file and does the processing perfectly. I also tried using `File.Create` and `File.CreateText`, but all produce the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`File.AppendText` creates a `StreamWriter` - which you're then not disposing, so the underlying handle is still open.

If you just want to create an empty file, I'd just use `File.WriteAllBytes(path, new byte[0])` - that way there's nothing to dispose. Or you could use

```cs
using var stream = File.Create(path);
```

... and then let it dispose of itself...